# django admin crashes when trying to update record but not when inserting a new one

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

I'm having a weird problem:

technical info for developemnt (production will be on linux/apache/Mysql)
macosx 2.6.6
python 2.6.1
django 1.3
mysql 5.1
and MySQLdb to connect the python to the MySQL...

I'm new at django as every one can see from past questions...but need to get really strong at it, really fast...the problem is that it is really not that smooth for me...

OK, for the question. I'm doing the django tutorial (not for fun, i need to learn it really fast because i need to develop a huge system with it).

I did all the the tutorial untill now and at the stage where i added the admin.

When i try to edit the poll record (if any one know the django 1.3 tutrial) the site crashes with the following exception:

> Warning at /admin/polls/poll/2/
>   Incorrect string value: '\xD7\xA9\xD7\x95\xD7\xA0...' for column 'change_message' at row 1

there is not problem with adding a new record to the same table, just to edit one....

if any one know's any thing about it....

```
# Create your models here.
```

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question

def was_published_today(self):
    return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()
```

This is the model, and another this i saw, my MySQL DB is latin1 and not UTF-8...python is unicode....maybe that is the problem....

But still, i can't figure out why i can add records but can't edit them....isn't that the weird part?

Comment: What kind of data have you entered for the poll?  Any non-english characters?

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: 10x, I've added some things.....thank you for helping and now, all the data i entered is in english....i things that it is the python-mysql encoding that is doing this....don't know what to do with it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a database character set issue. Can you check the default character set of auth_message table in your database?

If your table can't handle utf8 it would throw this error.

Comment: After seeing the bottom bit of your edit this is indeed the problem. I'm not sure why you can add entries either (maybe the python->mysql connector is doing some character conversion behind the scenes?), but I'm pretty sure this is your problem. Try running something like `ALTER TABLE auth_message CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`.

Comment: 10x, i've tried every thing...the table was set to latin and i've changed it to utf-8...but still getting the same message... p.s. what did i need to check in the table, other then that...the table is empty...just the chat set of the table is what iv'e changed

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE auth_message;` and it should show you the settings for the table itself. Additionally you might want to try setting the default collation/character set of your db itself.

Comment: 10x, got it solves....the all char set for the DB was bad.... I'm a beginner developer and working on a mac....i was working with a manual to install MAMP and work with that...but that Suc... bit time. in my opinion... it caused so many problems.... and now i have so many copies of every thing....but eventually managed to return to the MySQL from the MySQL website and working with the python server instead of Apache (for development only) because it seem that all the production stuff is really not for mac....(Apache, python<->MySQL<->MySQLdb) so returned to basic....

Comment: Now I just hope that when i install the production (Ubuntu 10.4 or 10.10..Don't know yet) it will work better....it's hard to go from MS to open source....very hard indeed...

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing same issue but using Django 1.4. I used the recommendation of *photoionized* but adapted to this version (where `auth_message` is gone, but you can find `change_message` in `django_admin_log`). So:

```
ALTER TABLE django_admin_log CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your mysql shell and run the following:

```
mysql> show variables like  'character\_set\_%';
```

Are there any `utf8` values from above?

Assuming it's a mysql issue, swap out your db settings to sqlite3:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database.sqlite3',           
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                  
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '',                   
    }
}
```

Sync and try to input some data again.

Comment: 10x, fixed it...but 10x again...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Column 'change_message' in the Table 'django_admin_log'. Change the character set to utf-8 default. Done